# Incrementing one value in an Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula in Excel that looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(posts!C12,users!A2:B1800,2)
```

I would like to duplicate this formula down the whole column, however, I would like C12 to increment (C13, C14, C15 etc), but for the rest of the formula to stay the same.

So far, I have tried duplicating it manually onto the next 4 or 5 cells, then selecting those and double clicking the bottom right hand corner of the selection, however this doesn't work, almost, but not quite.

Answer (score 8):

Add a dollar sign `$` before each coordinate that you want to be fixed.  I.e., if you want C12 to turn into C13, do `$C12` and the C will be fixed but the 12 will increment.  IF you want both values to be fixed, use `$C$12`.

Comment: another neat way to do this is to click on the range you want to change and press F4 until the $s are as you like them. Also I would be careful that your lookup range stays static     users!$A$2:$B$1800